# How to save 'Screen'-type gradients?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I am very new to Illustrator. Could you help me with following question:

Creating a gradient with a Screen-overlay type (near opacity selection) makes your radial gradient a glow pattern, removing the black circle around it.

[image]

But when saving to SVG the black circle appears.

[image]

How do I get rid of it ?

Comment: Hi Anton, could you add the svg code at the question please?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nxg5f9   -  this is the effect i created in Illustrator to make a glowing point. It uses a Screen blending mode with a gradient Fill.
If i try to save it my svg looks like this - http://prntscr.com/nxg685
If i try to Rastr it - glowing points simply dissapear from image saved in SVG. 
I know why... cuz its SVG format

I simply want same glowing effect in my resulting SVG icon.

Comment: It would be more useful to see the svg code since I can not reproduce the problem, everything works correctly with gradients in screen blending mode in svg.

Comment: i have been able to add  mix-blend-mode: multiply; to paths that i need - that makes my svg icon look same as in illustrator. But i am not sure if this is the correct solution taking in account support of that feature in browsers. Can u clarify about this solution ? 
May be it's better to reproduce same glowing points without blending mode but i don't know what way to go to make it

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine using screen blending mode in svg. If this is a problem in your svg, instead of using blending modes, you can use a gradient with the same color and different opacities, from 100% to 0%:

[image]

Comment: did u add manually blending mode in svg code ?

Comment: No, I saved the svg with the blend.

Comment: Is this Adobe Photoshop ? Cuz i am trying to achive it with Illustrator

Comment: Is Illustrator.

Comment: Then can you pls tell more about proccess of saving. I am saving to SVG 1.1 or 1.0 and it cuts away all blending

Comment: As I wrote you in the question comments, please add the svg code to see the mistake or omission.

Comment: all my paths are simply saved with gradient like this(even that i have screen mode selected in illustrator): 

````xml
<radialGradient xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="SVGID_30_" cx="197.2561" cy="227.9115" r="22.4666" gradientTransform="matrix(3.7037 0 0 3.7037 -319.366 -710.3699)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:#FFFFFF"/>
    <stop offset="0.1237" style="stop-color:#A6DEEF"/>
    <stop offset="0.1414" style="stop-color:#9ACEDE"/>

<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="fill:url(#SVGID_30_);" d="M494.4,133.7c0,40-83.27..."/>
````

Comment: sorry for messed up code. i dont understand how to paste it in comments here.

so all my paths that has any sort of blending mode just saved with gradientramp id and with a defined section of that gradients. i tried saving in different ways(svg 1.0, 1.1, tiny) , with attributes, with styles etc....

Comment: you cant paste multiline code into comments

Answer (score 0):

Huge numbers of these Blending modes in the Transparency panel (like Screen) are not bolstered by the SVG file format. So these should be rendered into pixel parts, a procedure which is called flattening. For this, select the related articles and pick Object > Flatten Transparency. Note: the first components will be adjusted, so hold a unique Illustrator record when sparing the modified form to SVG. Hope this will help you.